# robot_self_filter in hydro

Tags: moveit, ros-hydro, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a pointcloud from a laserscan and would like to filter out all points which belong to my robot itself. This could be done by the robot_self_filter, but as far as I know the whole arm_navigation stack which also includes this filter is deprecated since groovy. Is there any equivalent filter functionality in its successor MoveIt?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/112026/robot_self_filter-in-hydro/) by [Tones](https://answers.ros.org/users/3551/tones/) on ROS Answers with karma: 635 on 2013-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm also looking for it. Check this:

http://answers.ros.org/question/69004/robot-self-model-filter-for-depth-sensor-in-ros-hydro/

also check my question about taking robot_self_filter out of MoveIt!

http://answers.ros.org/question/165676/take-3d-self-filter-out-of-moveit/

---

Originally posted by [mark_vision](https://answers.ros.org/users/11321/mark_vision/) with karma: 275 on 2014-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1